# How to search for a values of Child in firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference=mDatabase;
        String queryText="Hotel";
        databaseReference.orderByChild("Coupon")
                .startAt(queryText)
                .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff");
```

> Here I attached the code which I used to get child names of "Coupon" when I entered the "Hotel" query under the Coupon.But I got blank.I supposed to get Hotel1,Hotel2 object.I'm new to firebase.So hope your support .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, you're trying to perform a `SELECT * FROM Coupon where coupon LIKE 'Hotel%'` right?

Comment: Yes.when we consider SQL that is correct.I need to use this as my search query.

Comment: Could you add more details on why your structure is like that? I can't seem to figure out why you have Hotel1/Hotel2 as your key when you are having that data inside it again.

Comment: Actually I need to add Coupons related  to Hotels.So I created Coupon child and add children to it with the name of Hotel.that is the structure which I put in that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Web version, they use something called ElasticSearch, you could try to read more here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html

But for Android, I think there isn't any functionality to perform a search like that. What I would do is to query all the records then filter them myself:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabase;
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot val : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        //I am not sure what record are you specifically looking for
        //This is if you are getting the Key which is the record ID for your Coupon Object
        if(val.getKey().contains("Hotel")){
            //Do what you want with the record
        }

        //This is if your are querying for the hotel child
        if(val.child("hotel").getValue(String.class).contains("Hotel")){
            //Do what you want with the record
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
```

}

Comment: Yes I saw there is good solution for web.But I could not find that kind of thing for android.Any way thank you for the help.let me check then I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Technically, it would return all hotels but you are checking each record if it contains "Hotel" in the record so, yes, it would return the records with "Hotel" or whatever search query will you add.

Comment: it's seems like a good solution for my work.but if it will be a large data set we are get  in to a  trouble.because we have to load all the data when we click search .

Answer (score 2):

Don't load your whole database to filter out needed data. It produces  unnecessary traffic which has to be loaded, calculated and deleted. Instead, use:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getDatabaseReference();

Query searchQuery = myRef.child("Coupon").orderByChild("hotel").equalTo("yourSearchString");
```

To make this code work, you also have to add `indexOn` on your corresponding attribute in the rules (of Firebase Database console).

Comment: no this only return matched data but he need all data but sorted by a hotel only